# An item with the same key has already been added C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm trying to browse all *.txt files from folder to get metadata inside.

```
void SearchAndPopulate(string path, string searchText)
        {

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
            Dictionary<String, dynamic> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                dictionary.Add(String.Format("name{0}", i.ToString()), i);
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName))
                {
                    string content = sr.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
                    if (content.Contains(searchText.ToLower()))
                    {
                               dictionary["name"+i] = File
                            .ReadAllLines(file.FullName)
                            .Select(y => y.Split('='))
                            .Where(y => y.Length > 1)
                            .ToDictionary(y => y[0].Trim(), y => y[1]);
                        var temp = dictionary["name" + i];
                        listBox1.Text = temp["NUM_CLIENT"];

                    }
                }
                i++;
            }


        }
```

I get **"An item with the same key has already been added"** for dictionary variable.

Comment: You are adding the value of I inside the foreach loop on a dictionary. Cant add the same I each time bro.

Comment: As far as I can see you don't need that dictionary with the dynamic type in the first place since you only ever use the item with key `"name" + i` and `i` is incremented at the end of each loop.  Just use a local variable for your Linq result.

Comment: @Botonomous it's not the same `i` since there's a `i++;` at the end of the loop

Comment: You have key with more than one value so you need Dictionary<string, List<Object>>

Comment: Clearly it is tho.

Comment: @juharr before use dictionary i had try with a simple var, but i get also `An item with the same key has already been added`

Comment: @Botonomous No the issue is occurring with the `ToDictionary` call.  The other dictionary is a red herring.

Comment: @Bissap That's likely because your have a file that has multiple lines that have the same value on the left side of an equals sign.  The `ToDictionary` will throw that error if you fed it something that will generate duplicate keys.

Comment: @juharr i check my files (metadata), it's ok i have just `NUM_CLIENT=5555
NUM_FACTURE=008
NUM_BL=258`

Comment: Also why are you reading the contents of the file twice?  Once with `sr.ReadToEnd()` and then again with `File.ReadAllLines`?

Comment: @Bissap Is there only one file?  Also, If you get the same error with a local variable or using the dictionary then obviously you don't need the overhead of a dictionary that uses a dynamic type.

Comment: Honestly you don't even need `ToDictionary`.  Just find a line that starts with "NUM_CLIENT" and if found set it to your list box.

Comment: @juharr why i reading twice time cause i beginner, no there 5 files (metadata). I just would like get metadata into a variable and put it in listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I don't think you need any dictionaries in your code.  Also you can reduce the number of times you read in each file.

```
void SearchAndPopulate(string path, string searchText)
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        var content = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName);
        if (content.Any(line => line.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())))
        {
            var numClient = content.Select(y => y.Split('='))
                .Where(y => y.Length > 1 && y[0].Trim() == "NUM_CLIENT")
                .Select(y => y[1])
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if(numClient != null)
                listBox1.Text = numClient;
            else
                // Do something here if "NUM_CLIENT" wasn't in the file.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This exception is thrown when you try to add a duplicate entry in a Dictionary using the same key. The key value in a Dictionary must be unique.

Possible causes

1. Look at the content of your file, you will find at least 2 lines where the left side of the `=` sign have the same string value.
2. You have multiple empty values on the left side of the `=` sign in your file. You can correct this in your Linq statement by ignoring those lines:

   ```
   dictionary["name"+i] = File.ReadAllLines(file.FullName)
       .Select(y => y.Split('='))
       .Where(y => y.Length > 1 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(y[0]))
       .ToDictionary(y => y[0].Trim(), y => y[1]);
   ```

Comment: It's either 1 or 3.  The files are each handled separately because of the `i++;`